# Remove "Warning!" on Solana Explorer

Tags: explorers

How do we remove this warning for out token? Is there a whitelisting process? Our token is unique and this is being displayed on the correct mint.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That error is shown because your token is not verified. This is the code that is responsible for that warning.

```
if (!data?.nftData?.metadata.data.uri && tokenDetails) {
  token = tokenDetails;
} else if (data?.nftData) {
  token = {
    logoURI: data?.nftData?.json?.image,
    name: data?.nftData?.json?.name ?? data?.nftData.metadata.data.name,
  };
  unverified = true;
} else if (tokenDetails) {
  token = tokenDetails;
}
```

Solana Explorer uses Solana token List to fetch and display the metadata of verified tokens. If your token is unverified, metadata is not provided and thus unverified is set as true and that warning is displayed. You need to verify your token using Solscan. But there is no guarantee that your token will be accepted or not.